# Absolute continuity of geometric sum of ergodic random variables.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

I have a stationary ergodic process of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a constant $r<1$. Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(\log^+|X_1|)<\infty$. Then the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^nX_n 
$$
converges, see for example lemma 2.1 of [this link](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1169571804).

**Question:** Assume all the $X_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Is the sum then absolutely continuous too? If not, are there extra assumptions that ensure this result?